# CSV file generation error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

I'm working on a project for a client - a wordpress plugin that creates and maintains a database of organization members. I'll note that this plugin creates a new table within the wordpress database (instead of dealing with the data as custom_post_type meta data). I've made a lot of modifications to much of the plugin, but I'm having an issue with a feature (that I've left unchanged).

One half of this feature does a csv import and insert, and that works great. The other half of this sequence is a feature to download the contents of this table as a csv. This part works fine on my local system, but fails when running from the server.  I've poured over each portion of this script and everything seems to make sense. I'm, frankly, at a loss as to why it's failing.

The php file that contains the logic is simply linked to. The file:

```
<?php
    // initiate wordpress
    include('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

    // phpinfo();    

    function fputcsv4($fh, $arr) {
        $csv = "";
        while (list($key, $val) = each($arr)) {
            $val = str_replace('"', '""', $val);
            $csv .= '"'.$val.'",';
        }
        $csv = substr($csv, 0, -1);
        $csv .= "\n";
        if (!@fwrite($fh, $csv)) 
            return FALSE;
    }

    //get member info and column data
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "member_db";
    $year = date ('Y');
    $members = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name, ARRAY_A);
    $columns = $wpdb->get_results("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table_name, ARRAY_A);
    // echo 'SQL: '.$sql.', RESULT: '.$result.'<br>';

    //output headers
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"members.csv\"");

    //open output stream
    $output = fopen("php://output",'w'); 

    //output column headings
    $data[0] = "ID";
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($columns as $column){
        //DIAG: echo '<pre>'; print_r($column); echo '</pre>';
        $field_name = '';
        $words = explode("_", $column['Field']);
        foreach ($words as $word) $field_name .= $word.' ';
        if ( $column['Field'] != 'id' && $column['Field'] != 'date_updated' ) {
            $data[$i] = ucwords($field_name);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $data[$i] = "Date Updated";
    fputcsv4($output, $data);

    //output data
    foreach ($members as $member){
        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($member); echo '</pre>';
        $data[0] = $member['id'];
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($columns as $column){
            //DIAG: echo '<pre>'; print_r($column); echo '</pre>';
            if ( $column['Field'] != 'id' && $column['Field'] != 'date_updated' ) {
                $data[$i] = $member[$column['Field']];
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $data[$i] = $member['date_updated'];
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
        fputcsv4($output, $data); 
    }
    fclose($output);
?>
```

So, obviously, a routine wherein a query is run, `$output` is established with `fopen`, each row is then formatted as comma delimited and `fwrite`d, and finally the file is `fclose`d where it gets pushed to a local system.

The error that I'm getting (from the server) is

```
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.
```

But it clearly is getting found, its just failing. If I enable `phpinfo()` (PHP Version 5.2.17) at the top of the file, I definitely get a response - notably `Cannot modify header information` (I'm pretty sure because `phpinfo()` has already generated a header). All the expected data does get printed to the bottom of the page (after all the phpinfo diagnostics), however, so that much at least is working correctly.

I am guessing there is something preventing the `fopen`, `fwrite`, or `fclose` functions from working properly (a server setting?), but I don't have enough experience with this to identify exactly what the problem is.

I'll note again that this works exactly as expected in my test environment (localhost/XAMPP, netbeans).

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

#### update

Ok - spent some more time with this today. I've tried each of the suggested fixes, including @Rudu's `writeCSVLine` fix and @Fernando Costa's `file_put_contents()` recommendation. The fact is, they all work locally. Either just `echo`ing or the `fopen`,`fwrite`,`fclose` routine, doesn't matter, works great.

What does seem to be a problem is the inclusion of the `wp-blog-header.php` at the start of the file and then the additional `header()` calls. (The path is definitely correct on the server, btw.)

If I comment out the `include`, I get a csv file downloaded with some errors planted in it (because `$wpdb` doesn't exist. And if comment out the `header`s, I get all my data printed to the page.

So... any ideas what could be going on here?
Some obvious conflict of the wordpress environment and the proper creation of a file.

Learning a lot, but no closer to an answer... Thinking I may need to just avoid the wordpress stuff and do a manual sql query.

Comment: Give a try to file_put_contents() instead fwrite() function if you want to write the file to your disc. Otherwise if you want just to print the contents on the screen, then use print or echo. It always work just fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I'm wondering why you've taken this approach.  Nothing wrong with [`php://output`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) but all it does is allow you to write to the output buffer *the same way as `print` and `echo`*... if you're having trouble with it, just use print or echo :)  Any optimizations you could have got from using `fwrite` on the stream then gets lost by you string-building the `$csv` variable and then writing that in one go to the output stream (Not that optimizations are particularly necessary).  All that in mind my solution (in keeping with your original design) would be this:

```
function escapeCSVcell($val) {
    return str_replace('"','""',$val);
    //What about new lines in values?  Perhaps not relevant to your
    // data but they'll mess up your output ;)
}
function writeCSVLine($arr) {
    $first=true;
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        if (!$first) {echo ",";}
        $first=false;
        echo "\"".escapeCSVcell($v)."\"";
    }
    echo "\n"; // May want to use \r\n depending on consuming script
}
```

Now use `writeCSVLine` in place of `fputcsv4`.

Comment: As I noted, and maybe I didn't make myself completely clear, this is borrowed code - a publicly available wordpress plugin that I have been modifying to meet my needs for this project. This element simply didn't work once loaded to the server. I will definitely try out your modifications. Honestly, the dev did do a few odd things throughout, which I had to alter, but I hadn't touched this feature, as it was working fine, locally. Thanks for the relpy!

Comment: thanks for the help, but I'm no closer to an answer. Check out my reply?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same issue. Stumbled upon this thread which does the same thing but hooks into the 'plugins_loaded' action and exports the CSV then. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/how-can-i-force-a-file-download-in-the-wordpress-backend

Exporting the CSV early eliminates the risk of the headers already being modified before you get to them.

Comment: Hells bells man. Thanks for posting. I never did get this figured out (have a sloppy hack working for the client atm)  - I'll give this a try asap.

Comment: This is one of those really hard problems to describe. So I'm glad I stumbled on to this thread first. Gave me ideas which eventually led me to my answer. Thanks!